# Angular Promise : unable to get value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, promise

I'm coming from the python world, and am a beginner in Angular / ts / js way of programming.

The `Ionic storage.get()` method returns a `Promise`. How should I get the value of token in order to send it with my http query ?

For now, i'm trying this faulty bloc :

```
get(url: string): Observable<Response> {
  let token = "";
  this.storage.get('token')
      .then(token => token = token);

  return this.http.get(url, { "Authorization" : token});
}
```

Of course, the request leaves with token = "" instead of the one that should have come back after the promise resolution.

I can see not other method in Promise than `then()` and `catch()`. I have considered the following code :

```
get(url: string): Observable<Response> {
  return this.storage.get('token').then(
    token => {
      return this.http.get(url, { "Authorization": token } )
  );
});
```

But then, `get(url)` returns a `Promise<Observable<Response>>` instead of `Observable<Response>` and this does not help me much.

If the anwser lies within the use of defer ($q https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) , someone please could tell me how this class can be imported into angular / ionic ?

Thank you for your assistance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `$q` is used in AngularJS to deal  with promises. Here in Angular you would be using `Observable` mostly.

You could use `Observable.fromPromise` to convert promise to Observable followed by `flatMap`, so it will ultimately return an Observable of `Response` Type.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';

get(url: string): Observable<Response> {
  let token = "";
  return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('token'))
      .flatMap(token => this.http.get(url, { "Authorization" : token}));
}
```

Comment: Hi @pankaj-parkar. Thanks for your answer. I get "[ts] Property 'fromPromise' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'." I'll try to fix it asap but if you have any hint, would be welcome :)

Comment: @Paul did you added `Observable` import?

Comment: Yes, I have these two lines in my code : 
`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/fromPromise';` But I have no`fromPromise.js` in `rxjs/add/operator` so I guess this is normal. Or not... ?

Comment: My bad, the import should be `import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';`

Comment: @Paul can you create a plunker/fiddle?

Comment: Yes ! Found fromPromise thanks to your comment :) And I also added `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';` for `flatMap` (begin to understand how it works ;) Now I try your solution.

Comment: @Paul oh. glad to know that mine 2 cent helped, Thanks ;)

Comment: It works ! I'm still not out of the woods, but the token is sent. Many thanks ! :)